# What is the Samsung Galaxy S3's Heap Size?

Tags: out-of-memory, android-animation, heap-memory, galaxy

I have a small animation (`AnimationDrawable`) that consists of 9 frames with resolution of 480x800.

When I was running that activity with the animation on my "old" SGS1 everything was fine. Now I got the S3 and the exact same code gave me an `outofMemoryError`. That's not what I'd expect of a QuadCore/1GB RAM mobile phone. When I reduced the resolution of the animation, everything worked fine.

Did they really reduce the memory/heap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examine the /system/build.prop file and look for 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' - that supposedly is the value for memory heap size allowed for each application process

Comment: I actually will get my hand on a S3 today (hopefully). I can share what I see.

Comment: Thanks. So keep an eye open. When I added some Animations I got those problems with the Heap whereas I didn't see any problems at my old S1.

Comment: Have you take a look how you handle Bitmap? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I recently have to resolve a OutOfMemoryError issue on newer device and my conclusion at the end is that Android BitMap is very tricky and memory leak can easily happen. Once I properly handle the BitMap, then I was actually able to get the app running on old HTC G1 with only 16MB of heap memory.   9 frames of 480 x 800 shouldn't used up that much memory to a point that application run out of heap. I would recommend closer review of your animation implementation, otherwise, you might always run into OutOfMemoryError with other devices.

Comment: I just found that the option "android:largeHeap" might help but it works only for devices with Android 3.0 or higher. :-(

Answer (score 4):

On my S3 running Android 4.1.2 **the max heap size is 64MB** (67108864 bytes).

You get this number by calling `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();`

I've seen mention of 256MB but this is most likely only for apps that have specified `android:largeHeap` in their manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

its 256mb on stock s3 .  you should be handling bitmaps on native heap instead using .InPurgeable option